# How to stream video with RPi 3 and a common webcam?

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, webcam

I have a RPi 3 with the latest Raspbian and a simple webcam. I would like to stream the video through it using Pi IP. I tried to follow this tutorial:
http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/
But I didn't find `webcam_localhost off`. After that I read this tutorial wasn't for RPi3. Anyone has any tip about it? I'm a real beginner and I would like to found some clear tutorial about it.

Comment: please follow all steps, hope you will get solution.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeyBu-Mzeq4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Motion's](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) options changed since your linked tutorial was written. The config option you were looking for (`webcam_localhost off`) seems to have been changed to `control_localhost`:

> control_localhost
>
> Values: on, off
>
> Default: on
>
> Limits the http (html)
>   control to the localhost. This option must be placed in motion.conf
>   and not in a thread config file.

With a little luck the [latest documentation](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigFileOptions) should provide equivalents to the options you need.